# mysql query showing 9 results

Tags: php, mysql, mysql5

i have a problem.

I'm running following query. I have only one record in my database but i'm getting 9 results.

```
SELECT c.id, c.rk 
FROM cv AS c, employee AS e , cvCat AS cv_cat 
WHERE c.status=1 
    AND c.empIDFK = e.id 
    AND cv_cat.categoryFK IN ( 17,18,19,38,39,40,41,44,45,46 ) 
    AND cv_cat.cvFK = c.id
```

Can someone please let me know if they is any problem with this query. Why i'm getting 9 results rather then just 1 result.

This query should only display one record but its showing 9 results.

Comment: why cannot you make `JOIN` query like normal people write it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
FROM cv AS c, employee AS e , cvCat AS cv_cat
```

You are doing an implicit join of the three tables. If you want to get distinct records you can add `DISTINCT` after your select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.rk 
FROM cv AS c, employee AS e , cvCat AS cv_cat 
WHERE c.status=1 
    AND c.empIDFK = e.id 
    AND cv_cat.categoryFK IN ( 17,18,19,38,39,40,41,44,45,46 ) 
    AND cv_cat.cvFK = c.id
```

Comment: It should not make your query take much more time than it already is. If the `DISTINCT` columns you are selecting are indexed, then mySQL will be able to use that index to return distinct records. If the columns are not indexed, then mySQL will create a temporary table to compute the distinct records. If you prefix your query with `EXPLAIN`, you can check the last column labeled `Extra` and it will tell you whether it will use an index or a temporary table to return the distinct results.

Comment: i am indexing the id. its my primary key.

Comment: Perfect, in that case you will be good. Try it, you will see :)

Answer (score 2):

Use explicit joins:

```
SELECT c.id, c.rk
FROM cv c
INNER JOIN employee e ON e.id = c.empIDFK
INNER JOIN cvCat cv_cat ON cv_cat.cvFK = c.id
WHERE c.status = 1
AND cv_cat.categoryFK IN (17,18,19,38,39,40,41,44,45,46)
```

Comment: @Lalajee You'd need to follow zi42's advice and add the keyword `DISTINCT` after your `SELECT` if that's the case.  If your results before were 9 rows of the exact same data, adding `DISTINCT` will only output a single row.  Without knowing the data in your tables or the exact output the amount of advice that can be given is limited.  As for speed, using explicit joins should actually speed things up more than anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think the 9 result row "issue" is based on your JOIN syntax, as that kind of implicit join will return all rows (of each table) as a joined result, since you are only pulling out c.id and c.rk it may look like MySQL sent the same result back 9 times.

Side Note: Implicit joins are being deprecated, using explicit joins, such as...

```
    SELECT c.id, c.rk
    FROM cv c
    LEFT JOIN employee e ON c.empIDFK = e.id
    LEFT JOIN cvCat cv_cat ON c.id = cv_cat.cvFK
    WHERE...
```

Will help "future-proof" your code a bit and add a little more self-describing syntax to the whole query.

Comment: Whats the different between left or inner join.